# Cannot publish to Maven central (keep getting 401)

Tags: maven, gradle

Recently I was trying to publish to maven central, but without success.

I created an account using my `github` account, thus i now have a verified namespace `io.github.smyrgeorge` under namescpaces tab.

I also generated a `User token` in the `View account` page, so as a result I got something like:

```xml
<server>
    <id>${server}</id>
    <username>A_USERNAME</username>
    <password>A_PASSWORD</password>
</server>
```

Then from my project I tried to publish to maven, but without success.

I'm using `gradle` with the `maven-publish` plugin, my config is as follows:

```kotlin
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "OSSRH"
            url = uri("https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/")
            credentials {
                username = "A_USERNAME"
                password = "A_PASSWORD"
            }
        }
    }

    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
            from(components["java"])
            artifactId = tasks.jar.get().archiveBaseName.get()
        }
    }
}
```

So, I keep getting the following error:

> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':actor4k:publishMavenJavaPublicationToOSSRHRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'OSSRH'
> Could not PUT 'https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/io/github/smyrgeorge/actor4k/0.1.0/actor4k-0.1.0.jar'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

I'm I missing something?

Comment: I have the same issue. I have tried all possible repositories, but the issue still persists.

Comment: @asissuthar check the answer below. I think for now is a nice workaround. When I have the full solution I'll come back again.

Comment: Thanks for below script, Yorgos. I had tried to create zip file manually and tried to upload to portal but it was failing because I guess something was missing in directory structure. There's also not enough documentation about it. I'll give it a try with your bash script.

Comment: I had contacted sonatype support team, They've replied "It appears that you are attempting to publish via the Central Publishing Portal via Gradle's "maven-publish" plugin. Unfortunately, the Portal does not yet support publishing via Gradle yet, as it is still in early-access.". So I have used old way of publishing using gradle, It works perfectly using gradle

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of digging I finally managed to upload to Maven Central.

I managed to do it using the `Maven Central Portal`. You can find the instructions here: https://central.sonatype.org/publish-ea/publish-ea-guide/

*(Publishing using gradle still fails with 401)*

Basically you need to do the following steps:

- Generate a `gpg` key and publish it to a public key server
- Build and sign all artifacts with your `gpg` key
- Create a `.zip` bundle and upload it using the portal app

To create your `gpg` keys (otherwise you will not be able to publish the bundle) just follow the instructions here: https://central.sonatype.org/publish/requirements/gpg/

*Don't forget to publish your public key in one of the key servers that the document mentions.*

I also exported the private key in ascii format

```bash
gpg --output key-ascii.pgp --armor --export-secret-key example@info.com
```

The key and the password are used by `gradle` to sign the artifacts (see below the gradle script).

*Note: you need to remove the header and the footer of the key.*

I wrote a small `bash` script that creates the necessary bundle file.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

set -e

MAVEN_PROJECT=$(/bin/cat < settings.gradle.kts | grep 'rootProject.name =' | cut -d= -f2 | awk '{ print substr( $0, 3, length($0)-3 ) }')
MAVEN_GROUP=$(/bin/cat < build.gradle.kts | grep 'group =' | cut -d= -f2 | awk '{ print substr( $0, 3, length($0)-3 ) }')
MAVEN_VERSION=$(/bin/cat < build.gradle.kts | grep 'version =' | cut -d= -f2 | awk '{ print substr( $0, 3, length($0)-3 ) }')
MAVEN_PATH=$(echo "$MAVEN_GROUP" | tr . / | awk '{print $1"/'"$MAVEN_PROJECT"'"}'"$1")

./gradlew publishToMavenLocal

mkdir -p .gradle/bundle && cd .gradle/bundle || exit

cp -R ~/.m2/repository/"$MAVEN_PATH"/"$MAVEN_VERSION"/* ./

rm -rf ./*.module*
for file in ./*; do md5sum "$file" | awk '{print $1}' > "$file".md5; done
for file in ./*; do sha1sum  "$file" | awk '{print $1}' > "$file".sha1; done
rm -rf ./*.md5.sha1

mkdir -p "$MAVEN_PATH"/"$MAVEN_VERSION"
cp -R ./actor4k-"$MAVEN_VERSION"* ./"$MAVEN_PATH"/"$MAVEN_VERSION"

rm -rf ./actor4k*
rm -rf bundle-"$MAVEN_VERSION".zip
zip -r bundle-"$MAVEN_VERSION".zip io

rm -rf io
rm -rf coordinates-"$MAVEN_VERSION".txt
echo "$MAVEN_GROUP":"$MAVEN_PROJECT":"$MAVEN_VERSION" > coordinates-"$MAVEN_VERSION".txt

rm -rf ./bundle*.md5* && rm -rf ./bundle*.sha1*
rm -rf ./coordinates*.md5* && rm -rf ./coordinates*.sha1*
```

After running the previous script you can find the `bundle-x.y.z.zip` file in `.gradle/bundle` folder.

Below is the `gradle` file (that I'm using to build and sign the artifacts).
It's very important to provide the project information.

```kotlin
...
java {
    withJavadocJar()
    withSourcesJar()
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "OSSRH"
            url = uri("https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/")
            credentials {
                username = System.getenv("MAVEN_USERNAME")
                password = System.getenv("MAVEN_PASSWORD")
            }
        }
    }

    publications {
        val archivesBaseName = tasks.jar.get().archiveBaseName.get()
        create<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
            from(components["java"])
            artifactId = archivesBaseName
            pom {
                name = archivesBaseName
                packaging = "jar"
                description = "A small actor system written in kotlin using Coroutines (kotlinx.coroutines)."
                url = "https://github.com/smyrgeorge/actor4k"

                scm {
                    url = "https://github.com/smyrgeorge/actor4k"
                    connection = "scm:git:https://github.com/smyrgeorge/actor4k.git"
                    developerConnection = "scm:git:git@github.com:smyrgeorge/actor4k.git"
                }

                licenses {
                    license {
                        name = "MIT License"
                        url = "https://github.com/smyrgeorge/actor4k/blob/main/LICENSE"
                    }
                }

                developers {
                    developer {
                        name = "Yorgos S."
                        email = "smyrgoerge@gmail.com"
                        url = "https://smyrgeorge.github.io/"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

signing {
    val signingKey = System.getenv("MAVEN_SIGNING_KEY")
    val signingPassword = System.getenv("MAVEN_SIGNING_PASSWORD")
    useInMemoryPgpKeys(signingKey, signingPassword)
    sign(publishing.publications)
}
...
```

I hope this will be useful